# When doesn't a Mystic Wanderer AC bonus apply?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, armor-class

The Mystic Wanderer PrC (Magic of Faerûn p. 35) allows one to add Cha to AC:

> Glory of the Divine (Su): A mystic wanderer who wears no armor gains a sacred (or profane, if her patron deity is evil) bonus to AC equal to her Charisma bonus (if any).

Is there any circumstance when this AC bonus is **not applied**? Flat-foot? Touch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As long as magic is working, you get the bonus.**

If your Mystic Wanderer were in an antimagic field or a dead magic zone, this supernatural ability would stop working, so it wouldn't be applied then; and as the ability states, the Mystic Wanderer must not be wearing any armour. Otherwise, though, the bonus is universally applicable; there are no general circumstances in which *sacred/profane* bonuses are automatically excluded and the ability itself specifies no additional circumstances which are excluded, so it's always on and applies to any sort of attack, including touch attacks or when the Mystic Wanderer is flat-footed.